# rake db:migrate returning error rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake, migrate

I am getting an error while running rake db:migrate on windows

failed to execute:
pg_dump -s -x -O -f F:/Installer/humboldt-master/humboldt-master/db/structure.sq
l --schema=public --schema=postgis --schema=topology humboldt_dev

Please check the output above for any errors and make sure that `pg_dump` is ins
talled in your PATH and has proper permissions.

can someone help me to resolve this issue? I did some research on google but did not found any solution to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The error is suggesting that either

- You don't have `pg_dump` installed, or
- `pg_dump` isn't referenced in your PATH.

Make sure that you have `pg_dump` installed and that you have an environment variable pointing to its location and that should solve your issue.

Comment: I have already postgreSQL installed and I believe pg_dump installed with it. Also the path of the pg_dump is "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin\pg_dump.exe".

I tried to add pg_dump in Gem file but that also not help me.

Comment: I am betting that your do not have the `pg_dump` path set up as an environment variable. The program is assuming it can run the `pg_dump` program but it can't find it. Adding an environment variable to your PATH allows you to run the `pg_dump` process from within any folder on the command line.

I would do a Google search and find out how to add environment variables in Windows. [This guide](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/) might be a good resource.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer, I was running Postgres.app, which works really well, but it didn't give me access to command line tools until I ran:

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d &&
echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
```

You can read more about it here: [postgress app cli-tools documentation](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/cli-tools.html)